# How to identify the service name of a mail id

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

In node js I am sending mails using node mailer.

> var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
>       service : 'gmail',
>       auth : {
>           user : 'xyz@gmail.com',
>           pass : '*******'
>       }
>   });

This scenario was working fine.

Now I am going to use "invite@myhealthcircles.com" as mail id for authentication.

> var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
>       service : 'myhealthcircles',
>       auth : {
>           user : 'invite@myhealthcircles.com',
>           pass : '*******'
>       }
>   });

Now mails were not sending. Is the service name correct ? Or I have to give something else. If so , how to finde the service name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use nodemailer-smtp-pool module, and provide your email server credential in the option:

```
var mailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpPool = require('nodemailer-smtp-pool');
var option = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 25,
    auth: {
        user: 'your@email.com',
        pass: 'yourpassword'
    }
}

mailer.createTransport(smtpPool(option));

...
// to send the email
mailer.sendMail(...)
```

that is it.

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail service is configured by default in Nodemailer. If you want to use your own service, you need to provide the specific service name like webmail.myhealthcircles.com (it could be something else). Basically, it should be the same name as you provide if you were to configure this in microsoft outlook or any other mail client.

Comment: I tried  webmail.myhealthcircles.com, myhealthcircles,webmail. But none was working.

Comment: check with your smtp provider for the correct service name.